# How to get subset of List<T> items based on their Sum of an object property

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a subset of objects from a List based on the value of one of the object properties, specifically I want to get the first few objects based on the sum of their aggregated value of that property.

I could manually iterate through the list, add/Sum the value of the property and compare the result to my desired value, but is there a better way?

For example, imagine I have this list:

```
List<MyObj> MyObjList;
```

Where MyObj looks like this:

```
public class MyObj
{
  public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And MyObjList has the following objects and values, in this order:

```
MyObjList[0].MyValue = 1;
MyObjList[1].MyValue = 3;
MyObjList[2].MyValue = 2;
MyObjList[3].MyValue = 3;
MyObjList[4].MyValue = 2;
```

For example I might want to get the first few items where their collective sum of MyValue <= 5, which would return only the first 2 objects.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is a combination of Aggregate and TakeWhile, so let's write that.

```
public static IEnumerable<S> AggregatingTakeWhile<S, A>(
  this IEnumerable<S> items,
  A initial,
  Func<A, S, A> accumulator,
  Func<A, S, bool> predicate) 
{
  A current = initial;
  foreach(S item in items)
  {
    current = accumulator(current, item);
    if (!predicate(current, item))
      break;
    yield return item;
  }
}
```

And so now you can say

```
var items = myObjList.AggregatingTakeWhile(
  0,
  (a, s) => a + s.MyValue,
  (a, s) => a <= 5);
```

Note that I have made the decision here to consult the predicate *after* the accumulator has been updated; depending on your application, you might want to tweak that slightly.

Another solution would be to combine aggregation with enumeration:

```
public static IEnumerable<(A, S)> RunningAggregate<S, A>(
  this IEnumerable<S> items,
  A initial,
  Func<A, S, A> accumulator) 
{
  A current = initial;
  foreach(S item in items)
  {
    current = accumulator(current, item);
    yield return (current, item);
  }
}
```

And now your desired operation is

```
var result = myObjList
  .RunningAggregate(0, (a, s) => a + s.MyValue)
  .TakeWhile( ((a, s)) => a <= 5)
  .Select(((a, s)) => s);
```

I might have gotten the tuple syntax wrong there; I haven't got Visual Studio handy right now. But you get the idea. The aggregation produces a sequence of (sum, item) tuples, and now we can use normal sequence operators on that thing.

Comment: very elegant solution (+1) from me.

Comment: I was about to post almost the same solution... a tad too slow! Out of curiosity, I implemented `predicate` simply as a `Predicate<A>`. Is there a specific reason you chose a `Func<A, S, bool>`?

Comment: One of the things I like about this answer is that it's exposing me to bits of C# (Func) that I've never used before.

Comment: @InBetween: The general attitude on the C# team is that Predicate, etc, were unnecessary misfeatures. "Predicate" is self-documenting in that it tells you "this bool-returning delegate is used to make a decision", and that it is therefore logically distinct from a delegate that, say, deserializes a bool from a file. So it's nice, but do we *really* need to make that distinction *in the type system*? Do we really want to make people who have a `Predicate<int>` in hand and need a `Func<int, bool>` to make that conversion? No. Just use `Func` everywhere, consistently.

Comment: @InBetween: Now, if your question is why `A, S` rather than just `A` -- you might want to have something like "take these items until an item is twice as big as the running average so far", or something like that. In which case you need to have the current item as well as the accumulator in the predicate.

Comment: My question was more related to your second comment, and yes, adding `S` makes the solution much more flexible as to what conditions you can break on. Thanks.

Comment: @EricLippert I think there are missing type arguments S and A in the second solution (the method should be generic).

Answer (score 5):

For an old-school, non-Linq approach, you could write a simple method for this:

```
static List<MyObj> GetItemsUntilSumEquals(List<MyObj> items, int maxSum)
{    
    if (items == null) return null;

    var result = new List<MyObj>();
    var sum = 0;

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (sum + item.MyValue > maxSum) break;
        sum += item.MyValue;
        result.Add(item);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can add some kind of `int currentSum` to avoid re-calculating `result.Sum()` on each iteration. This leads also to a "Linq-free" solution.

Comment: @MartinBackasch very true! That would be better perf than all the summing.